# change dataframe name using cat()

Tags: r

Here is a data frame called x:

```
> str(x)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ : Factor w/ 8 levels "apple apple orange",..: 7 4 6 5 2 3 8 1 2
> x

1  dog dog cat hamster
2  cat cat dog hamster
3         cat fish dog
4 cat dog hamster fish
5  apple orange carrot
6    cabbage apple dog
7     orange cat apple
8   apple apple orange
9  apple orange carrot
```

If I do the following I can change the name variable in x to "cat":

```
> names(x) <- "cat"
> x
                   cat
1  dog dog cat hamster
2  cat cat dog hamster
3         cat fish dog
4 cat dog hamster fish
5  apple orange carrot
6    cabbage apple dog
7     orange cat apple
8   apple apple orange
9  apple orange carrot
> names(x)
[1] "cat"
```

But apparently not if I do the following:

```
> names(x)
[1] "cat"
> names(x) <- cat("cat",1)
cat 1
> x

1  dog dog cat hamster
2  cat cat dog hamster
3         cat fish dog
4 cat dog hamster fish
5  apple orange carrot
6    cabbage apple dog
7     orange cat apple
8   apple apple orange
9  apple orange carrot
> names(x)
NULL
```

Is it possible to dynamically give names to a df, (in this case will be in a loop with e.g. `names(df) <- cat("group",1)`

Comment: I think you might be looking for [`paste0()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html). The [`cat()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html) function does not concatenate strings, it is used for printing output.

Comment: OK, got it thank you very much